# How can I map the ADGuid Property for import in the User Profile Service Application?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I am trying to use the User Profile Service Application to import the ADGuid (Active Directory ID) from Active Directory into SharePoint 2010.  There is already a default property to store this data, however I am having difficulty in setting up the mapping.  The issue is that I am unable to edit any of the attributes on the "Edit User Profile Property" page for the ADGuid (Active Directory ID).

For example, when I am editing the property settings for ADGuid, when I go to select a direction of Export and click Add, nothing happens.  It does not appear in the propery mapping for synchronization.  Also, I am unable to check the box in the "Display Settings" section that says "Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page"

Any ideas on how to control this property like you can other properties being exported from AD?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you actually want to edit the value from AD?? If you are importing it, what is the purpose of exporting it?

Comment: No I do not want to edit it.  I simply want to display the objectGUID in SharePoint and possibly reference it in future applications that we may build.

Comment: I am confused, you say the issue is you cannot edit the values.